# AWS EC2 took too long to respond

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following the Amazon course AWS Technical Essentials, and I am in lecture 2: Demonstration: Launch the Employee Directory Application on Amazon EC2.

I have followed all the steps and successfully launch the instance. But in the last step, when I tried to browse the web using Public IPv4 DNS, it respond that it 'took too long to respond'. I have searched for solutions but most of them are for SSH connection, and I also did not include key pairs because the instructor did not. The port 8080 is the solution from another post, I tried it but it does not solve the problem.

Below are my inbound and outbound. Could anyone give me suggestions on how to fix it?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: The configurations you have shown seem fine. It's hard to know what else might be wrong. I'd simply suggest trying it again and see whether it works. I'm not sure how the Lab is setup, but perhaps the instance was launched in a private subnet instead of a public subnet, or the User Data used to launch the instance failed (make sure there's no empty line at the top).

Comment: How can I check if it is launched in the private subnet or public subnet? I think I will add more pictures of the setup process.

Comment: I am searching for how to open the internet gateway. Hope it works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: The problem was that my internet gateway was in the blackhole status i.e deleted or detached from VPC, so after attaching the IGW to the VPC, the issue was fixed. (Also make sure, The security group or network ACL does allow access to the instances with HTTP/HTTPS/SSH protocol.)

Useful Resources:-

[Create and attach internet gateway to a VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-attach-igw-vpc/)

[Connect to the internet using an internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)

[Control traffic to resources using security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

Hope this will be helpful to someone!

Comment: @thang-Dinh, commenting here as I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question, May be you have already figured it out if not, can you please once check if you added HTTP OR HTTPS type for security group inbound rules? If only added for HTTP, please make sure to use HTTP only in the instance public IP address or dnsname.